# field alignments in django crispy forms and bootstrap 3?

Tags: django, django-forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

I am using `django-crispy-forms` and `Bootstrap 3` in my template rendering.
Here is how my form looks like:
[image]

As you can notice, the fields are not aligned correctly. I want them to be inline. please provide suggestions on how to fix this:

My crispy form code is below:

```
class SortFieldsForm(forms.Form):
    latest_year=forms.BooleanField(label="latest year")
    newest_entry=forms.BooleanField(label="newest post")
    price_order=forms.ChoiceField(
                    widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                    label="price order",
                    choices=(('lowest_price','lowest '),('highest_price','highest'),),
                    initial="lowest_price",
                    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.helper.field_template='bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = '.'

        super(SortFieldsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            InlineRadios('price_order'),
            'newest_entry',
            'latest_year',
             Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='button white'),
        )
```

And the generated HTML code:

```
<form  action="." id="id-exampleForm" class="form-inline" method="post" >
    <div id="div_id_price_order" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_price_order"  class="control-label  requiredField">
            price order
            <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="controls ">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="price_order" id="id_price_order_1" value="lowest_price" >lowest</label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" name="price_order" id="id_price_order_2" value="highest_price" >highest</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_newest_entry" class="checkbox">
        <label for="id_newest_entry" class=" requiredField">
            <input class="checkboxinput checkbox" id="id_newest_entry" name="newest_entry" type="checkbox" />
            newest post
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="div_id_latest_year" class="checkbox">
        <label for="id_latest_year" class=" requiredField">
            <input class="checkboxinput checkbox" id="id_latest_year" name="latest_year" type="checkbox" />
            latest year
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary button white" id="submit-id-submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with crispy-forms itself, but rather that you have a label on the radio inputs that is pushing the actual inputs down. You need to add a margin-top style to `div_id_newest_entry`, `submit-id-submit`, and `div_id_latest_year`. For example (your use case may vary a bit), in your CSS file:

```
#div_id_newest_entry,
#div_id_latest_year,
#submit-id-submit {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: but I see that submit button is very close to fields and all the buttons are closed packed. I want space separations and I also need a fieldset  around price order

Comment: This is also a CSS issue. You'll need to add some padding. Instead of the above, maybe something like `margin: 25px 10px 0px;`.

Comment: I would need a fieldset around the radio-select button (for price order) so that it stands out

Comment: What do you mean by "so that it stands out"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: currently, all fields are in one line, I want radio buttons to have feildset around it, so that it is different from other checkboxes

Comment: The django crispy forms gives default id such as submit_id_submit and if I have many forms, the css will be applied to all of them. I am wondering if there is a way to give a unique id during form construction in django crispy forms

Comment: This is a completely different question than your original. The short answer is yes. https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/d-0/layouts.html

Comment: well, I read through the documentation before I posted here. I am intereseted in fieldset around radiobuttons. if you know of any relvant material in crispy documentation, let me know